# Sign-in after Firebase.goOffline()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, offline

Is it possible for a user to sign in after ***Firebase.goOffline()*** was called in Android? Suppose,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    <sign-in anonymous>
```

Now, if somehow **Firebase.goOffline()** was called anywhere in the code, will the user be able to sign in again when he/she starts the activity again (without destroying the app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online/offline functionality of Realtime Database in no way affects how Firebase Auth works.  When you tell Realtime Database to go offline, all that does is affect the way that database queries work.  It doesn't affect any other Firebase products that you might be using in the app.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  I suggest posting a new question showing specific code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Can you kindly explain the difference between **Firebase.goOnline()** and **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline()**? When I tried to post this question, it said, _Many such questions received downvotes or have been closed_.